# Creating two tabhosts in one app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I am making an android application in which I use two different tabhosts in two different activities, However I am having trouble differentiating between then and my app stops when I enter the activity with the second tabhost.

The code in my first activity is as follows:

```
private TabHost tHost_;
private TabSpec tSpec_;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mypls_shared);
        setTitle("Workout Scheduler");
        tHost_ = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tHost_.setup();
        tSpec_ = tHost_.newTabSpec("tag1");
        tSpec_.setContent(R.id.myTab);
        tSpec_.setIndicator("My Workouts");
        tHost_.addTab(tSpec_);
        tSpec_ = tHost_.newTabSpec("tag2");
        tSpec_.setContent(R.id.shareTab);
        tSpec_.setIndicator("Shared Workouts");
        tHost_.addTab(tSpec_);

    }
```

in my xml file the android id of the tabhost is specified as follows:

```
<TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
```

the code in my second file is as follows:

```
private TabHost tHost_;
private TabSpec tSpec_;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_three_by3);
    setTitle("Workout Scheduler");
    tHost_ = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tHost_.setup();

}
```

the xml file looks like this:

```
<TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >
```

However when I enter the second activity, the app stops. I know that a tabhost must be named as such:

```
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
```

but what do i do if I have 2 tabhosts, which is referred to by `R.id.tabhost`?

Comment: You can use the same id in different layouts, I think that you are running into another problem, what is the log output?

Comment: 11-02 00:43:34.015: W/dalvikvm(9386): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4199e300)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Keb3mr.workoutscheduler/com.Keb3mr.workoutscheduler.ThreeBy3}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)

Comment: 11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: 11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

Comment: 11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at com.Keb3mr.workoutscheduler.ThreeBy3.onCreate(ThreeBy3.java:20)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)

Comment: 11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)

Comment: 11-02 00:43:34.019: E/AndroidRuntime(9386):  ... 11 more